# NestJS not handling error from thrown from service in controller

Tags: nestjs

I have a simple setup where I'm calling a service method from the controller like so:

```js
// companies.controller.ts

@Controller("company")
export class CompaniesController {
  constructor(private companiesService: CompaniesService) {}

  @Post("/:id/upload")
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor("file"))
  uploadFiles(
    @Param("id") id: string,
    @UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>,
  ) {
    // throw new HttpException("Company not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    // console.log(files);
    try {
      this.companiesService.uploadFiles(id, files);
      console.log("didn't get error");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("got error");
      throw new HttpException("forbidden", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
  }
}

// companies.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class CompaniesService {
  constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService,
    private s3Service: S3Service,
    private filesService: FilesService,
  ) {}

  async uploadFiles(id: Company["id"], files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
    const company = false // for testing

    if (!company) {
      console.log("Company not found");
      throw new Error();
    }
}
```

I'm running this by using `nest start --watch`.

When I call this endpoint, My app quits and I get the following logged to my console:

```
didn't get error
Company not found

/src/companies/companies.service.ts:54
      throw new Error();
            ^
Error: 
    at CompaniesService.uploadFiles (/src/companies/companies.service.ts:54:13)
```

How come I can't catch the error I'm throwing in my controller? It's clearly not `catch`ing because it's logging `company not found`. Exception Filtering is supposed to be built in by default so I'm not sure why this isn't producing a `500`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't `await`ing the `this.companiesService.uploadFiles(id, files);` call, which means that it is an unhandled promise. If anything errors from it, it's an unhandled rejection. Just add `async` to the `uploadFiles` in the controller and `await` to the`this.companiesService.uploadFiles` call and you should be good to go

Comment: Yes, that was it! I knew it had to be something silly I was missing. Thank you!